# Error: your connection to this site is not private Asp.Net. MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-server-2016, iis-10

I'm setting up a new server with windows Azure VM for a asp.net mvc 5 application. I'm able to open every page of the application without a problem with an exception of one controller. i.e. whenever I try to open a page belong to a specific controller, it prompts me for user name & password as below.

[image]

I use the same application in a different Windows Server 2016 VM without any issues.

I don't see any errors of the application/IIS logs either. I don't have any https requirements in the application.

What may be causing this behaviour?

```
namespace App.Controllers
{
    public class ReportsController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly IReportRepository reportRepository;
        public ReportsController(): this(new ReportRepository()){
        }

        public ReportsController(IReportRepository reportRepository){
        this.reportRepository = reportRepository;
        }

        public ViewResult Action()
        {
           return View(reportRepository.All);
        }
    }
 }

namespace App.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class BaseController : Controller
    {
    }
 }
```

**UPDATE**: I renamed the ReportsController to AppReportsController and the issue disappeared. 
i.e. I get the above prompt when I try to access

> http://domain/Reports/Action

but not for

> http://domain/AppReports/Action

Could you please someone explain to me what's going on here? Does it mean that "Reports" is reserved by the framework or something?

Comment: If you don't use transport layer security (i.e. HTTPS!) then the browser will tell you this because you are sending credentials over an insecure connection that can easily be sniffed by a malicious person.

Comment: If that's the case, how do other pages work properly? all other controllers are also inherited with BaseController.

Comment: You will see that message any time you see the password popup and your connection is not secure.

Comment: From the picture you're using HTTP (without S suffix) and the password input generally used for submitting secret credentials when logging in, therefore triggers security issue warning when using insecure protocol.

Comment: User had logged in to the application before this particular page is loaded. I only received this prompt for any action belong to ReportsController. I don't see this prompt for any other page from different controllers.

Comment: If your users are required to log in, then you always have https requirements. Using http will send user names and passwords as plain text over the internet.  Its generally a good idea to use https as a best practice, since it will encrypt all traffic to and from the website, making it more secure by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this was an old post however I stumble on this one because I encountered the same error as the OP does.

I have solved this one in case there's someone encounters the same as this.
but the solution may vary depends if we have the same applications installed.

1. check if the web server / server has an installation of sql server.
2. check if there is reporting services installed.
3. remove / uninstall the reporting services from the application control panel
   follow this link if you don't know how to remove the report service [How to remove Report Service](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/49fc8761-205b-42bb-b1a2-182ea1b2a119/how-to-uninstall-reporting-services-on-sql-2008-r2?forum=sqlreportingservices)
4. Please check again if you still encounter the same error. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The browser will tell you your connection to the site is not private if you don't use [transport layer security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) (i.e. HTTPS) in your web application, and you are being asked to enter data - in this case your credentials. Doing this is dangerous because that data can easily be sniffed by a malicious person.

There is no reason in today's world to not have a secure site, I strongly recommend you get a certificate (they are [free and super easy](https://www.troyhunt.com/https-is-easy/)!)

Comment: I understand the security concerns when sending sensitive information over http instead https.  but it's irrelevant for my issue here.

Comment: I promise you that it's not irrelevant, otherwise you wouldn't have put that page behind a login in the first place. If you're happy exposing your data then remove the login.

Comment: I appreciated your answers and trying to help me here. But do you think if I remove the login, it will solve the issue that I'm facing here?

Comment: If you remove the login then that message won't appear, yes. However if you have any data entry you may get other warnings. Also, Chrome (and possibly other browsers) will warn users by telling them the site is "Not secure".

Comment: But here browser doesn't complain about site is being insecure. it says site is not private. I feel that I'm missing some configuration in the server as same application works fine in a different server without any prompts.

Comment: FYI, I have just tried without the login and I get the same prompt.

Comment: What prompt are you talking about? The screenshot you show is the login prompt which will obviously go away.

Comment: Nothing to do with HTTPS / TLS, I had a similar issue, in my case I created a REST endpoint which required some authentication headers. If one attempts to access the endpoint without supplying said auth headers, the screen as shown above "Your connection to this site is not private" will appear.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use "Reports" use "Report" instead. Controller name ReportController not ReportsController. It'll be alright. I've faced the problem and this is the solution I've got.

Answer (score 1):

This is an authentication issue. In my case, it solved by below steps: 
1- Go to IIS manager, in the left pane, expand the server root and select your web application from Sites node. 
2- In the Home screen, go to IIS section and select Authentication. 
3- Enable Anonymous Authentication. 
4- Then, select Edit and set Edit Anonymous Authentication Credentials to Application pool identity.

[image: Anonymous Authentication Credentials]

Comment: man i was wondering what is the problem for days, I disabled `Windows Authentication`  to make it work, thank you very much

Comment: SOlved my issue either. Thx